# how to run a main class from a jar in "test" folder

Tags: java, jar, cmd

I have this main class in my java/test project

I have created a jar and want to run this main method (under "test" folder)

[image]

how can I run it?

```
❯ java -jar UsersServer.jar -classpath  linqmap.users.CacheOnlyTestRunner                                                                         [13:25:24]
no main manifest attribute, in UsersServer.jar

    ❯ java -classpath UsersServer.jar linqmap.users.CacheOnlyTestRunner                                                                               [13:25:31]
Error: Could not find or load main class linqmap.users.CacheOnlyTestRunner

    ❯ java -cp UsersServer.jar linqmap.users.CacheOnlyTestRunner                                                                                      [13:25:49]
Error: Could not find or load main class linqmap.users.CacheOnlyTestRunner
```

Comment: run `jar -tf UsersServer.jar ` to check if there is a manifest file

Comment: there is. but when i run "java -jar UsersServer.jar " i get an error. What to do? "no main manifest attribute, in UsersServer.jar"